# Onclick not working in tablet

Tags: jquery, html, tablet

I have an image slider which is not working on tablet because I have use onclick everywhere. But when I write:

```
$('#myImageFlow').on("touchstart",".sliderImage", function(event){
    alert('i am on method '+event.type);
});
```

This line is my slider then alert is printed and slider works, if I try replacing alert with:

```
console.log('on method ......'+event.type);
```

Then it is not working. What would be the problem?

**HTML :**

```
<body style="background-image:url('img/Mesh2.png');background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size: cover; width=:'100%'">
    <h1>iSlider</h1>




    <!-- This is all the XHTML ImageFlow needs -->
    <div id="myImageFlow" class="imageflow">

    <div id="id1" alt='div1'class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img1.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">You've styled the div to have a set width of 100px. At a reasonable font size, that's too much text to fit in 100px. Without doing anything, the default white-space value is normal,
    and the text will wrap. See the example below or follow along at home with the demo.You've styled the div to have a set width of 100px. At a reasonable font size, that's too much text to fit in 100px. Without doing anything, the default white-space value is normal,
    and the text will wrap. See the example below or follow along at home with the demo.</div>
    <div id="id2" alt='div2' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img2.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 2</div>
    <div id="id3" alt='div3' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img3.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 3</div>
    <div id="id4" alt='div4' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img4.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 4</div>
    <div id="id5" alt='div5' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden; background-image:url('img/img5.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 5</div>
    <div id="id6" alt='div6' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img6.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;"> this is 6</div>
    <div id="id7" alt='div7' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img7.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;"> this is 7</div>
    <div id="id8" alt='div8' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img8.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 8</div>
    <div id="id9" alt='div9' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img9.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;"> this is 9</div> 
    <div id="id10" alt='div10' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img10.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 10</div>
    <div id="id11" alt='div11' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img11.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 11</div>
    <div id="id12" alt='div12' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img12.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 12</div>
    <div id="id13" alt='div13' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img13.jpg');border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 13</div>
    <div id="id14" alt='div14' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img12.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;">this is 14</div>
    <div id="id15" alt='div15' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img6.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;"> this is 15</div>
    <div id="id16" alt='div16' class="sliderImage" width="300" height="360" onclick="" style="visibility:hidden;background-image:url('img/img7.jpg'); border:solid; border-color: black;"> this is 16</div>



    </div>




</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vclick`

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#myImageFlow', function () {
    // your scripts
});
```

Comment: what is your jquery version?

Comment: $('#myImageFlow').on("touchstart",".sliderImage", function(event){//}); you want to use #myImageFlow or .sliderImage?

Comment: @yeyene  i dont want to print or write anything but onclick should work on tablet

Comment: Try one of these two?...$("#id").click(function () { // }); or $('#id').on('click', function() { // });

Comment: @yeyene ????  i dont want to print anything , onclick not working on tablet so just want to make click work on tab

Comment: can we see your html and more js? pls, may be jsfiddle.

Comment: @yeyene html page i have added ... cant make js fiddle very difficult

Comment: humm, this plug-in is also using vclick, $(image).bind('vclick ', function () { my.glideTo(this.i);}); ! Have you tried testing this original plugin demo is working on iPad or not?